# Monitor date wise log using zabbix

Tags: zabbix

I want to monitor below log file in zabbix

/var/log/syslog-ng/local/2017-07-24/localhost/ALL

In syslog-ng log files will create in every day with date wise folder 
like below path.

/var/log/syslog-ng/local/2017-07-24/localhost/

I need to know how to specify date wise folder path in zabbix key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script to find the entry of the string for which you want alert for in the log file  and then can raise alert based on a log file to which you write your output if that entry is found in the log file or not.